# $X \subseteq Y \subseteq Z$ and $X \approx Z$ indicate $Y \approx Z$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am proving the following theorem:

> $\aleph_{\alpha} + \aleph_{\beta} \approx \max{\left\{\aleph_{\alpha},\aleph_{\beta}\right\}} = \aleph_{\max{\left\{\alpha,\beta\right\}}}$, where $\aleph$ is the class function from ordinals to initial ordinals ($\aleph_{\boldsymbol{0}} = \omega$, $\aleph_{\gamma^{+}} = \textrm{ least initial ordinal } \alpha \textrm{ such that } \aleph_{\gamma} \prec \alpha$, $\aleph_{\lambda} = \bigcup\left\{\aleph_{\gamma}: \gamma \in \lambda\right\}$ if $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal), and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals.

Here is my incomplete argument. The relation holds if $\alpha = \beta$ (proved). Next, without loss of generality, assume that $\alpha < \beta$. As
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{0} < \aleph_{\beta}, 
\end{equation*}
we have
\begin{equation*}
\aleph_{\beta} \leq \aleph_{\alpha} + \aleph_{\beta} \leq \aleph_{\beta} + \aleph_{\beta}.
\end{equation*}
It is already known that
\begin{equation*}
\aleph_{\beta} + \aleph_{\beta} \approx \aleph_{\beta}.
\end{equation*}
Then if we can prove the following lemma:

> $\left(X \subseteq Y \subseteq Z \wedge X \approx Z\right) \Longrightarrow Y \approx Z$,

the theorem at the beginning is proved. Of course, we may assume that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are well-ordered, if it is necessary for the proof, as ordinals are well-ordered. Can anyone suggest how to construct a bijection between $Y$ and $Z$?

Comment: Schroeder-Bernstein...

Comment: The Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem gives it to you without well-ordering anything.

Comment: @user10354138 I almost forgot about this. There is some gap between me reading these two chapters. Is that symmetric $\preceq$ leads to $\approx$?

Comment: @ZiqiFan: Yes: if there are injections $A\to B$ and $B\to A$, then there is a bijection between $A$ and $B$.